# How to set :hover on QMenu?

Tags: c++, css, qt, qt-creator

I'm working with QT and I have a menu. I have the follwing css for the menu:

```
QMenu {
   /* background-color: #0F7070;*/
    background-color:rgb(44,63,80);
    border-top: none;
    border-left:none;
    border-right:none;
    border-bottom:4px solid  rgb(44,205,112);;
    color:#fff;;
}

QMenu::item {
    spacing: 3px; /* spacing between menu bar items */
    padding: 10px 85px 10px 20px;
    background: transparent;
}
/*Does not work*/
QMenu::item:hover {
    background-color: rgb(52,73,94);
    border-top: none;
    border-left:none;
    border-bottom:none;
    border-left:3px solid  rgb(44,205,112);;
}
```

How can I set the :hover to the item? Thank you.

Comment: I don't recognise that syntax. What is `::item` and is `QMenu` a class or an element?

Comment: QMenu is the class of the widget. ::item is the element of the QMenu, something like <li> in HMTL. If I set QMenu::item:pressed it works, however it does not with :hover.

Comment: According to the documentation (stylesheet examples) that should work: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html **example given:** `QListView::item:hover {
    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                stop: 0 #FAFBFE, stop: 1 #DCDEF1);
}` If the selectors are not invalid, the issue must stem from another source.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had same issue few years ago with a QT project.
Even if it may look like conterintuitive i solved changing:

```
item:hover
```

to

```
item:selected
```

I was advised so on QT forum, in that contest `:selected` acted as `:hover`, i didn't get deeper in the question, maybe won't work, but it worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

I intend to set the background color of the QWidget

```
QWidget {
    background-color: white;
}
```

But later, when the menu QAction is selected, the font is white, and the background is also white.The menu button font and background can be reset in the following ways

```
QMenu::item:hover {}
```

to

```
QMenu::item:selected {}
```

This way works, thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33827847)